# Django get() calls in Celery tasks return 32 matches

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am observing a very weird bug with Celery. Some of the code in my tasks file make some get requests that I am certain should return 1 result, but they sometimes return 32 results. When this error occurs, the number of results returned  is always 32.

Here are the exceptions from two different get calls:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one User -- 
  it returned 32! Lookup parameters were {'id__exact': 9503}

MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Avatar -- 
   it returned 32! Lookup parameters were {'id__exact': 372}
```

This is never an issue with the non-celery views. I am also using johnny-cache, so I suspect it might be the culprit, making the get() request to memcache instead of the database.
Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this was related to using johnny-cache and celery. Removing johnny cache, we no longer have any problems.